# What is the correct swagger-annotation for this requestBody?

Tags: java, swagger

We try using *swagger 2.0 (OAS3)* for the documentation of a Restful API, implemented in *Java* and based on Apache CXF (jaxrs).
For a handful API-Calls yet implemented, the documentation with swagger works fine, but the following Post-Request makes me struggling:

```
@POST
@Path("/documents")
@Consumes("multipart/mixed")
Response createDocument(
    @RequestBody(description = "RestDocumentParams (required), InputStream and RelationshipParams",
                 content = { @Content(mediaType = "multipart/mixed", schema = @Schema(implementation = RestDocumentParams.class)),
                     @Content(mediaType = "application/octet-stream", schema = @Schema(type = "string", format = "binary")),
                     @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = RelationshipParams.class)) })
    @Multipart(value = "doc", type = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        RestDocumentParams documentParams,
    @Multipart(value = "file", type = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, required = false)
        InputStream inputStream,
    @Multipart(value = "rela", type = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, required = false)
        RelationshipParams relationshipParams)
```

This method should create a new Document using at least the data given in *RestDocumentParams*. Optionaly a file object (*InputStream*) and additional
MetaData (*RelationshipParams*) can be provided. All this payload has to be provided in the RequestBody.

Using this method in a testframework (e.g. *restassured*) works fine. 
My problem is, how I have to annotate this method correct with swagger-annotation, to use it in Swagger-UI.

Using the RequestBody-Annotation like above, seems not being the right way!
In Swagger-UI appears a combo-box within the description of the RequestBody and let me choose the three different media types.
But if I want to try out this method and edited one of the input parameters (e.g. entering a file name) and choose the next media type, the last editing is lost.

Comparing the *json-Strukture* of the requestBody for this method with the OAS3 definition for "multipart content" differ. 
Regarding to the OAS3 definition, the requestBody should have look like this:

```
  requestBody:
    description: 'RestDocumentParams (required), InputStream and RelationshipParams'
    content:
      multipart/form-data:
        schema:
          properties:
            docParams:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/RestDocumentParams'
            relaParams:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/RelationshipParams'
            fileName:
              type: string
              format: binary
```

But I don't know how I have to specify the requestBody (using swagger annotoations) to achive a structure which looks like this.